# Replace array of string with other array of string?

Tags: c#, arrays, csv

i need to replace matched element of my array with element of other array
i write this code :

```
    string[] replace(string[] input)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (input[i])
            {
                case "a":
                    input[i] = "11";
                    break;
                case "b":
                    input[i] = "22";
                    break;
                case "c":
                    input[i] = "33";
                    break;
                default:
                    input[i] = "??";
                    break;
            }
        }
            return input;
    }
```

but can you give me the better method to this work ?

Comment: Can you be more clear? What are you actually trying to ask? What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: Will the inputs contain only characters from a-z?

Comment: Keep in mind, that if you change `input` array in your method by the way you do, your original array will be changed too, because arrays are reference types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a dictionary that maps from source to target  elements. According to the sample You posted, something like `Dictionary <string, string> mappingsDictionary;` can be used.

In order to define mappings, You add appropriate pairs consisting of original element and a string to replace it in the result array, like `mappingsDictionary.Add ("a", "11");`.

Then, one of the ways to use it would be calling `var resultArray = myOriginalArray.Select(i => { string s; return mappingsDictionary.TryGetValue(i, out s) ? s : i; }).ToArray ();`.

If elements in both input and output array are strings, You can also use `StringDictionary`.

Comment: if key not found in dictionary , how can return some default value for it ?

Comment: The method `TryGetValue(...)` returns `false` if specific key is not found in the dictionary. In my answer, the code tries to get value for key `i` and returns value of `i` itself, if it's not found in the dictionary.

Comment: thanks, mappingsDictionary.TryGetValue(i, out s) ? s : "0"; }).ToArray ();